# Print values using multi-dimensional array in Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I try to learn about array types. Following code I used for multi dimensional array and It did't give correct result set. It gave `users=[[Ljava.lang.String;@2d68be1b` as output. What are the changes I need to do?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class Array_MultiDimentional2 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String[][] users;
            String email = null;
            String name = null;
            String pass = null;
            users = new String[][] {{email, name, pass }, {"one", "two", "three"}};
            System.out.println("users=" + users);

        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want to store structured data (like pairs of email, name, pass) in Java, then declaring a **class** is recommended. It makes your code **compile safe** and helps to keep the code **readable**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Dynamic way to Print Your Array

Java has a nice utility class called [`Arrays`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) which contains many handy methods for dealing with arrays. One of them is called `deepToString`, which is what we'll use:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Array_MultiDimentional2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] users;
        String email = null;
        String name = null;
        String pass = null;
        users = new String[][] {{"email", "name", "pass" }, {"one", "two", "three"}};
        //System.out.println("users=" + users);
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(users));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print a multidimensional array like that, you could write some for cycles like:

```
for (int i=0; i<users.length; i++) {
   for (int j=0; j<users[i].length; j++) {
      System.out.println(users[i][j]);
   }
}
```

It is not so optimal, but it could help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print elements in this array, how about to try this one.

```
for(int i=0; i<users.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<users[0].length; j++)
                System.out.print("users=" + users[i][j] + " ");
            System.out.println();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly print Array to get it's value(either one-dimensional or multidimensional). You have to print each value contain in the Array. For this example you can use:

```
for (int i=0; i<users.length; i++) {
   for (int j=0; j<users[i].length; j++) {
      System.out.println(users[i][j]);
   }
}
```